# android fragment inside individual item of recyclerview

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

Hi I am exploring recycler view of android.I want to inflate a fragment inside the each item of recycler view.I want to change the layout of item in recycler view by clicking on item.Any Ideas on how to approach this problem

Comment: sonuds like a problem for sure! what is the scenario where you would want to do this? sounds like it goes against alot of conventions and norms

Comment: Why are you trying to inflate a fragment instead of a view?

Comment: What I am trying to do is change the layout of the item in recycle view on clicking on it

Comment: I had problem that fragment displayed only for the first item. I solved the problem by setting new unique id for container layout before adding fragment. This answer helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42994810/1931613. For example, myContainerLayout.setId(SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis().toInt())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... recyclerview is not for that, is it for recycle views ^^, if you want to dislpays fragments in a 'list' you can create a class extending LinearLayout which will display your fragments.

Comment: What I am trying to do is change the layout of the item in recycle view on clicking on item.

Comment: ok i see, can't you update your adapter when you receive the click event and then, notify the adapter the data set change to update the ui ? i hope you will find a solution.