# ViewPager or RecyclerView with fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am a little bit confused on how should I approach this particular case of doing some swipes between fragments.

So yea, I asked `ViewPager` or `RecyclerView`, because these 2 are my only options, if anyone can come up with a better idea, it is really welcome.

The flow is the following, I have a Main Timeline(`ListView`), each item of it opens a fragment with details about it. What I would actually want to do is to swipe between these full screen fragments without going back to MTL and open another item of the list.

You would ask me what I tried, well:
`RecyclerView - HORIZONTALLY oriented` as a root of the fragment, and each item of this RV had the details of each event. The problem with this is that it gets really buggy because I have a huge logic inside each item(like, another `RV - horizontally` , a `PagerView also horizontally` to swipe between images (or a youtube frame that is being played if is the case. Plus a lot of other stuff in this, so the logic of parent RV inside the `onBindViewHolder()` is really tricky.

Would be better to use a `PagerView` with fragments(since I have the DetailsFragment kind of ready) ? The problem here is that I need a certain number of swipes, right ?[image: Whole Fragment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with viewpager.

Because creating fragments inside recyclerview causes recyclerview performs to slow down.Also to create fragments in onBindViewHolder() dynamically every time you need different unique id of frame layout to load which will be tough to generate.

For more information on why recycler view is bad idea to load fragments check this.

[Fragment replacing in RecyclerView item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194653/fragment-replacing-in-recyclerview-item)

Also try to use the ViewPager with an implementation of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. The adapter will optimize the memory usage by destroying fragments that are not visible at a given moment.

Check the documentation for details and code sample.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: Yes I know, already kind of did this and was so buggy. But as I said, the problem with viewpager would be the number of swipes. Firstly I have 20 items in MTL, but there are way much more(when I'm at the bottom of it I request more from server)

Comment: yes I know..because previously I had tried to use fragments insided recyclerview in one of the project.It is very buggy and tough to use.                     As I said try to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter as it will hep to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question, what about my inside swiping ? Because it's the ViewPager swipe(which is horizontally) and inside this I will have another viewPager + a RV (both also horizontally).

Comment: what is  inside swiping ?Also you can directly show fragment inside viewpager no?again why a viewPager + a RV?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot with the full fragment. Under similar events I have a RV horizontally and on top where is the image, I have a PagerView to swipe between those pictures(2 pics in the above case)

Comment: main swipe should be recycler view and the second one i.e similar posts should be horizontal recycler view

Comment: because that contains just an image and a name which can be used inside a layout..onclick you can call the main viewpager with refreshed data

Comment: By main swipe you mean the swipe of whole fragment ? which we decided that it has to be PagerView?

Comment: ya make it simple..I think you can create a single fragment and many instance of that as viewpager is swiped...keep one main viewpager and a fragment..onswipe refresh its data..also similar items should be a horizontal recylerview whose layout should be inside the fragment.

Comment: It is already like this, we kind of misunderstood each other a bit. Indeed the fragment is always the same(layout doesn't change) what change is it's data. But I was asking if there would be any problem of the swipe. On my previous implementation with RecyclerView as the root, my inside elements(images & similar events) were not swiped.

Comment: I kind of have 2 swipes on each pagerview fragment to be more clear

Comment: ohk...if UI is same then you can use singl fragment and keep refreshing as user swipes

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I will mark this as right answer :) Really apreciated

Comment: Thanks a lot..happy that this cleared your confusion and helped you :)

Comment: I came back with a slight misunderstood of what's going on with this implementation. I understood that `PagerView` loads next page (by default), but somehow, my data for the events for the visible fragment is taken from next fragment...How could I handle this?

Comment: I dint understand your question..can u explain?

Comment: 'onInstantiateItem' I take my data based on position. But, last data saved on this variable is the one from next page not the current/visible one..

Comment: not visible in a sense?you have to save the data as member variable inside your pager adapter class

Comment: Maybe in the constructor of it. I see, that might help me. The biggest problem is not this, is that I have youtube video fragments playing in each page...and it fails each time for next fragment (because of the overlay problem). Anyway, thanks again for your answer